# fdisk - Hex codes list - which ones are NTFS or FAT 32 among the below list?

Tags: debian, fdisk, hexadecimal

Is it possible to assist me finding fat32 or ntfs codes among the below list?

```
Command (m for help): t
Selected partition 1
Hex code (type L to list all codes): L
  1 EFI System                     C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
  2 MBR partition scheme           024DEE41-33E7-11D3-9D69-0008C781F39F
  3 Intel Fast Flash               D3BFE2DE-3DAF-11DF-BA40-E3A556D89593
  4 BIOS boot                      21686148-6449-6E6F-744E-656564454649
  5 Sony boot partition            F4019732-066E-4E12-8273-346C5641494F
  6 Lenovo boot partition          BFBFAFE7-A34F-448A-9A5B-6213EB736C22
  7 PowerPC PReP boot              9E1A2D38-C612-4316-AA26-8B49521E5A8B
  8 ONIE boot                      7412F7D5-A156-4B13-81DC-867174929325
  9 ONIE config                    D4E6E2CD-4469-46F3-B5CB-1BFF57AFC149
 10 Microsoft reserved             E3C9E316-0B5C-4DB8-817D-F92DF00215AE
 11 Microsoft basic data           EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
 12 Microsoft LDM metadata         5808C8AA-7E8F-42E0-85D2-E1E90434CFB3
 13 Microsoft LDM data             AF9B60A0-1431-4F62-BC68-3311714A69AD
 14 Windows recovery environment   DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC
 15 IBM General Parallel Fs        37AFFC90-EF7D-4E96-91C3-2D7AE055B174
 16 Microsoft Storage Spaces       E75CAF8F-F680-4CEE-AFA3-B001E56EFC2D
 17 HP-UX data                     75894C1E-3AEB-11D3-B7C1-7B03A0000000
 18 HP-UX service                  E2A1E728-32E3-11D6-A682-7B03A0000000
 19 Linux swap                     0657FD6D-A4AB-43C4-84E5-0933C84B4F4F
 20 Linux filesystem               0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4
 21 Linux server data              3B8F8425-20E0-4F3B-907F-1A25A76F98E8
 22 Linux root (x86)               44479540-F297-41B2-9AF7-D131D5F0458A
 23 Linux root (ARM)               69DAD710-2CE4-4E3C-B16C-21A1D49ABED3
 24 Linux root (x86-64)            4F68BCE3-E8CD-4DB1-96E7-FBCAF984B709
 25 Linux root (ARM-64)            B921B045-1DF0-41C3-AF44-4C6F280D3FAE
 26 Linux root  (IA-64)             993D8D3D-F80E-4225-855A-9DAF8ED7EA97
 27 Linux reserved                 8DA63339-0007-60C0-C436-083AC8230908
 28 Linux home                     933AC7E1-2EB4-4F13-B844-0E14E2AEF915
 29 Linux RAID                     A19D880F-05FC-4D3B-A006-743F0F84911E
 30 Linux extended boot            BC13C2FF-59E6-4262-A352-B275FD6F7172
 31 Linux LVM                      E6D6D379-F507-44C2-A23C-238F2A3DF928
 32 FreeBSD data                   516E7CB4-6ECF-11D6-8FF8-00022D09712B
 33 FreeBSD boot                   83BD6B9D-7F41-11DC-BE0B-001560B84F0F
 34 FreeBSD swap                   516E7CB5-6ECF-11D6-8FF8-00022D09712B
 35 FreeBSD UFS                    516E7CB6-6ECF-11D6-8FF8-00022D09712B
 36 FreeBSD ZFS                    516E7CBA-6ECF-11D6-8FF8-00022D09712B
 37 FreeBSD Vinum                  516E7CB8-6ECF-11D6-8FF8-00022D09712B
 38 Apple HFS/HFS+                 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
 39 Apple UFS                      55465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
 40 Apple RAID                     52414944-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
 41 Apple RAID offline             52414944-5F4F-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
 42 Apple boot                     426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
 43 Apple label                    4C616265-6C00-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
 44 Apple TV recovery              5265636F-7665-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
 45 Apple Core storage             53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
 46 Solaris boot                   6A82CB45-1DD2-11B2-99A6-080020736631
 47 Solaris root                   6A85CF4D-1DD2-11B2-99A6-080020736631
 48 Solaris /usr & Apple ZFS       6A898CC3-1DD2-11B2-99A6-080020736631
 49 Solaris swap                   6A87C46F-1DD2-11B2-99A6-080020736631
 50 Solaris backup                 6A8B642B-1DD2-11B2-99A6-080020736631
 51 Solaris /var                   6A8EF2E9-1DD2-11B2-99A6-080020736631
 52 Solaris /home                  6A90BA39-1DD2-11B2-99A6-080020736631
 53 Solaris alternate sector       6A9283A5-1DD2-11B2-99A6-080020736631
 54 Solaris reserved 1             6A945A3B-1DD2-11B2-99A6-080020736631
 55 Solaris reserved 2             6A9630D1-1DD2-11B2-99A6-080020736631
 56 Solaris reserved 3             6A980767-1DD2-11B2-99A6-080020736631
 57 Solaris reserved 4             6A96237F-1DD2-11B2-99A6-080020736631
 58 Solaris reserved 5             6A8D2AC7-1DD2-11B2-99A6-080020736631
 59 NetBSD swap                    49F48D32-B10E-11DC-B99B-0019D1879648
 60 NetBSD FFS                     49F48D5A-B10E-11DC-B99B-0019D1879648
 61 NetBSD LFS                     49F48D82-B10E-11DC-B99B-0019D1879648
 62 NetBSD concatenated            2DB519C4-B10E-11DC-B99B-0019D1879648
 63 NetBSD encrypted               2DB519EC-B10E-11DC-B99B-0019D1879648
 64 NetBSD RAID                    49F48DAA-B10E-11DC-B99B-0019D1879648
 65 ChromeOS kernel                FE3A2A5D-4F32-41A7-B725-ACCC3285A309
 66 ChromeOS root fs               3CB8E202-3B7E-47DD-8A3C-7FF2A13CFCEC
 67 ChromeOS reserved              2E0A753D-9E48-43B0-8337-B15192CB1B5E
 68 MidnightBSD data               85D5E45A-237C-11E1-B4B3-E89A8F7FC3A7
 69 MidnightBSD boot               85D5E45E-237C-11E1-B4B3-E89A8F7FC3A7
 70 MidnightBSD swap               85D5E45B-237C-11E1-B4B3-E89A8F7FC3A7
 71 MidnightBSD UFS                0394EF8B-237E-11E1-B4B3-E89A8F7FC3A7
 72 MidnightBSD ZFS                85D5E45D-237C-11E1-B4B3-E89A8F7FC3A7
 73 MidnightBSD Vinum              85D5E45C-237C-11E1-B4B3-E89A8F7FC3A7
 74 Ceph Journal                   45B0969E-9B03-4F30-B4C6-B4B80CEFF106
 75 Ceph Encrypted Journal         45B0969E-9B03-4F30-B4C6-5EC00CEFF106
 76 Ceph OSD                       4FBD7E29-9D25-41B8-AFD0-062C0CEFF05D
 77 Ceph crypt OSD                 4FBD7E29-9D25-41B8-AFD0-5EC00CEFF05D
 78 Ceph disk in creation          89C57F98-2FE5-4DC0-89C1-F3AD0CEFF2BE
 79 Ceph crypt disk in creation    89C57F98-2FE5-4DC0-89C1-5EC00CEFF2BE
 80 OpenBSD data                   824CC7A0-36A8-11E3-890A-952519AD3F61
 81 QNX6 file system               CEF5A9AD-73BC-4601-89F3-CDEEEEE321A1
 82 Plan 9 partition               C91818F9-8025-47AF-89D2-F030D7000C2C
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs has a list of GUID partition types.

Comment: But you probably want "Basic Data": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_basic_data_partition "According to Microsoft, the basic data partition is the equivalent to master boot record (MBR) partition types 0x06 (FAT16B), 0x07 (NTFS or exFAT), and 0x0B (FAT32)."

Comment: In fdisk on Linux my ntfs partition  is  displayed in column Type as Apple TV recovery (to my surprise and wondering why), which is No 44 in your list.

Comment: @Asklep "to my surprise and wondering why" – See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exactly you are asking.

1. If you're asking what partition types can hold a filesystem of the type NTFS or FAT32, the answer is *any*. The type of a partition is only to "encode" the purpose of the partition in the partition table itself, i.e. without any need to examine data inside the partition (and this is usually a filesystem). One is not obliged to create a "matching" filesystem, technically it can be anything.

   However, some tools do expect specific filesystems inside partitions of specific types. While it's possible to create an arbitrary filesystem (or anything) inside a partition of an arbitrary type, some combinations may cause trouble.

   <sup>E.g. I managed to break my Debian by assigning the type "Linux temporary data" (it's not on your list, newer `fdisk` knows it) to a partition, not creating any filesystem there and rebooting the OS. Then systemd tried to mount it to `/var/tmp/`, failed, screamed and (effectively) died. I fixed this from a live USB distro. This was before I learned about [Discoverable Partitions Specification](https://uapi-group.org/specifications/specs/discoverable_partitions_specification/).</sup>

   And this brings us to…
2. If you're asking what partition types were created with NTFS or FAT32 in mind, then:

   - *Microsoft basic data* (EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7) for sure, although it may hold exFAT or other types of filesystems as well.
   - *Windows recovery environment* (DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC), I guess.
   - *EFI System* (C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B), kinda, but not strictly.

     > The EFI system partition is formatted with a file system whose specification is based on the FAT file system and maintained as part of the UEFI specification; therefore, the file system specification is independent from the original FAT specification. The actual extent of divergence is unknown: Apple maintains a separate tool that should be used, while other systems use FAT utilities just fine.

     <sup>([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition#Overview))</sup>
   - Probably *Lenovo boot partition* and similar types.
   - …

     I mean there probably are other types created for FAT32 or maybe for NTFS. Or there will be. Your question lists 82 types; in September 2023 `fdisk` in my Kubuntu knows 200 types. There is room for more. I see no point in even trying to identify them all, you don't need to know them all. When you're trying to read a filesystem, only the actual type of the filesystem matters. In other words NTFS is NTFS regardless of what the partition table tells you about the partition. When you're creating NTFS or FAT32, you just need to know one thing which is…
3. If you're asking what partition type you should choose when creating a partition where you are going to create a general-purpose NTFS or FAT32, then the answer is **definitely [*Microsoft basic data* (EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_basic_data_partition)**.

---

There is [that other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1756965/432690), IMO quite peculiar:

> It is Apple TV recovery, No 44 in the list. fdisk on Kubuntu shows ntfs (in KDE Partition Manager displayed as ntfs and definitely is ntfs) as Apple TV recovery.

Along with few comments, that answer sounds like *Apple TV recovery* was *the* type for NTFS. This begs for being addressed specifically.

*Apple TV recovery* + NTFS is technically possible (see the point 1 above). Somebody or something chose *Apple TV recovery* for the partition and (later or earlier) (the same or another) somebody or something created NTFS inside the partition.

*Maybe* even this is by design, I mean *maybe* even NTFS is the expected filesystem for such partition type (see the point 2 above). I totally don't know Apple TV, I cannot tell.

But the fact such combination exists somewhere in the world does not mean you or anyone should choose *Apple TV recovery* for a partition holding a general-purpose NTFS.

Answer (score -1):

It is Apple TV recovery, No 44 in the list.
fdisk on Kubuntu shows ntfs (in KDE Partition Manager displayed as ntfs and definitely is ntfs) as Apple TV recovery.

Comment: For god sake!!! No kidding???

Comment: No kidding, me too was  very much surprised