# why fdisk -l /dev/sdX not show under system the "Linux LVM"

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, lvm, fdisk

from  `fdisk -l /dev/sda` , we got the following

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2099199     1048576   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         2099200   482344959   240122880   83  Linux
```

usually under **system** we should get `Linux LVM` , since sda2 is LVM

```
vgdisplay | grep Format
  Format                lvm2
```

is it something that we need to ignore ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The id `83` in a dos partition table is a generic one for Linux filesystems; `8e` is a more specific one for Linux LVM.

The id of your `/dev/sda2` was a choice of whoever created the partition. The choice may have been explicit (he or she deliberately wanted `83`) or implicit (he or she chose not to change the default value of `83`).

The type of the filesystem (or another structure) inside the partition does not have to match the id. The id is only to "encode" the purpose of the partition in the partition table itself, i.e. without any need to examine data inside the partition (and this is usually a filesystem). One is not obliged to create a "matching" filesystem, technically it can be anything. E.g. you can create NTFS on your `sda2` and still keep id `83` (which would be misleading then); or you can change the id to whatever you want. It's *technically* totally possible, although in case of discrepancy between the id and the actual content some tools may misbehave (compare [this other answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1809749/432690), but note it's for GPT).

You don't need to ignore `83`. If you think `8e` fits your setup better, correct the id. On the other hand if everything works as-is then you don't necessarily need to correct the id. It's your choice. If `sda2` is indeed for LVM then most likely `8e` does fit the setup better.

To change the id of `/dev/sda2` to `8e`:

1. Run `fdisk /dev/sda`.
2. Cast the command `t`.
3. Choose the partition number `2`.
4. Choose (input) `8e` as the new type.
5. Examine the new partition table with `p`.
6. If everything looks fine, write the new partition table to the device with `w` (if not, abort with `q`).

Doing this when `/dev/sda` (including `sda1`, `sda2`) is in use may trigger a warning, but if it's only the id you're changing then the whole operation is safe.

Comment: can you update your answer - correct the id. ?